# When PHP Gearman client fails to connect to the server I get the same code as when it fail to get new jobs

Tags: php, gearman

PHP Gearman worker retrieves tasks from the server. When we don't have any new tasks we do some other work in the background. Please check the implementation below.

```
$worker = new GearmanWorker();
$worker->addServer('host', 123);
$worker->addFunction('name', array($this, 'function'));
$worker->setTimeout(5000);

while ($worker->work() || GEARMAN_TIMEOUT == $worker->returnCode()) {
    if (GEARMAN_TIMEOUT == $worker->returnCode()) {
        $this->handleTimeout();
    } elseif (GEARMAN_SUCCESS != $worker->returnCode()) {
        $this->handleFail();
        break;
    }
}
```

The code looks very simple and works normally most of the times. But when for some reason the script fails to connect to the server the `$worker->returnCode()` is equal to `GEARMAN_TIMEOUT`.

The `$worker->returnCode()` value is the same

- when we don't have any new tasks
- when script fails to connect to the server

When script fails to connect to the server the error message and code are the following:

- `$worker->error()`

  gearman_worker_grab_job(GEARMAN_TIMEOUT) Option timeout return reached -> libgearman/worker.cc:869
- `$worker->getErrno()`

  0

**How to catch error when client fails to connect to server?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have added [`GearmanWorker::echo()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/gearmanworker.echo.php) call to check if the Gearman server is available.

Look at the code after changes

```
$worker = new GearmanWorker();
$worker->addServer('host', 123);
$worker->addFunction('name', array($this, 'function'));
$worker->setTimeout(5000);

while ($worker->work() || GEARMAN_TIMEOUT == $worker->returnCode()) {
    if (GEARMAN_TIMEOUT == $worker->returnCode()) {
        $this->handleTimeout();
        $echo = @$worker->echo(1);
        if (!$echo) {
            echo 'Failed to connect to Gearman Gerver.'. PHP_EOL;
            break;
        }
    } elseif (GEARMAN_SUCCESS != $worker->returnCode()) {
        $this->handleFail();
        break;
    }
}
```

Please note the line `$echo = @$worker->echo(1);` and checks bellow. If server is unavailable then `echo()` output PHP warning and returns `false`.

[`GearmanException`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.gearmanexception.php) is never thrown in our setup.

Answer (score 1):

For basic solution you can use code like this:

```
try {
while ($worker->work() || GEARMAN_TIMEOUT == $worker->returnCode()) {
    if (GEARMAN_TIMEOUT == $worker->returnCode()) {
        echo "Timeout...\n";
    } elseif (GEARMAN_SUCCESS != $worker->returnCode()) {
        echo "Fail...\n";
        break;
    }
}
} catch (GearmanException $e) {
  echo "Exception caused!\n";
}
```

But you can not leave worker alive, because it needs to connect. I suggest to use Supervisord for automatically restart workers.

Comment: Kirill, thank you for the comment. The issue is that we don't get any exception. Script fails to connect to the Gearman server. The `$worker->returnCode()` returned is `GEARMAN_TIMEOUT`. It acts like we don't have any jobs in the queue.

Comment: May be I don't understand the question. Are you need to catch timeout case in a gearman-client, instead of in worker? Because your script doesn't fails, it's got a timeout status. But error from $worker->error() looks like server is down, but in this case you can catch the exception.

Comment: Kirill, I think we have found the solution which works for us. Exception is not thrown in our setup. We are using latest Gearman PHP extension from PECL. When the Gearman server is not running we don't get any exception or even any warning until we try to do the `echo()` call. And the `echo()` for non available Gearman server issues PHP warning but not exception. In our real production script we send notification and die, because the script is managed with supervisor. Without try/catch statement the script should have died but it has not. Thank you for your help.